Nonnegative intersection with curves implies nonnegative self-intersection
Suppose $S$ is a smooth projective surface over an arbitrary field $k$. A curve on $S$ means a 1-dimensional closed subscheme. Let $NS(X)$ denote the Neron-Severi group and $NS_\mathbb{R}(X) := NS(X) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\alpha \in NS_\mathbb{R}(X)$ such that
$(\alpha. C)  \geq 0  $
for every curve $C$. Why does this imply that $(\alpha. \alpha) \geq 0$?

This is Kleiman's theorem, see Lazarsfeld's Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I, theorem 1.4.9. Let me give an idea of the proof.
Assume $\alpha\in NS_{\Bbb Q}(X)$. Fix $H$ a very ample divisor on $X$. Consider the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by  $$t\mapsto (\alpha+tH)^2 = \alpha^2+2t\alpha.H+t^2H^2.$$ By assumption, $2\alpha.H\geq 0$ and $H^2>0$, so if $\alpha^2<0$ there would be a unique $t_0>0$ so that $f(t_0)=0$. Writing $$f=\left(\alpha.(\alpha+tH)\right)+ \left(tH.(\alpha+tH)\right),$$ the right term is positive at $t=t_0$, so if we could prove the left term was non-negative at $t_0$, we would show that in fact $f(t_0)>0$ and hence $\alpha^2\geq 0$. To show this, by a continuity argument it's enough to show that $\alpha+t_1H$ is ample for all $t_1>t_0$, which follows by Nakai-Moishezon. The extension to $NS_{\Bbb R}(X)$ comes from another continuity argument by carefully approaching $\alpha$ by elements of $NS_{\Bbb Q}(X)$.
